# SVG with embed tag: Safari doesn't scale right

Tags: javascript, css, html, svg

I'm trying to add svg's to my "sheets reader" with the embed html-tag. It works fine in FF, in Chrome, even in IE9, but when I open the page in Safari, it's not scaling and I'm getting scrollbars.

Here's my testing environment: http://www.nie-wieder.net/br/BookReaderDemo/noten.html#page/1/mode/1up
just open it in safari (version 5.1.7, perhaps on mac only?! just got a mac right here) and you'll know what I mean.

So, my Question is: Is there any way to get the svg file at the demo to scale right in Safari?

I searched around here and found nothing to this specific question, so I hope you can help me :)

edit: I can't use img because svg via img-tag are not scriptable :(

Comment: I see what you mean... Nice app, by the way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You override your browsers default CSS rules for svg tag. Remove `width=""` and `height=""` from the svg tag in your `.svg` file or embed the svg as img instead of embed tag:

```
<img type='image/svg+xml' src="file.svg" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" />
```

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning this in my question, now I edited it in. I can't use img because we want to script with the svg files later on and svg over img-tag isn'T capable to.

Comment: then just try to remove width and height from your svg file or override the values with your script

Comment: Thanks for your tips. Here's my conclusion: First I tried to add width / height = 100% to my embed tag -> didn't work, safari didn't scale no matter what. Then I tried to use your "img"-snippet: Works like a charm, but as said, it's not scriptable. Finally I used object-tag and it didn't work either. So I'll just wait for a better version of safari and use svg in all the other major browsers (or at least tell safari to gtfo of my page ;) ) Anyway, thank you.

Comment: Open your Web-Inspector, navigate through your elements to the svg tag and simply remove width and height attributes. I could not access the element by JavaScript, otherwise I would have written a little script. (Safari 5.1.7)

Comment: This is what I get: http://nie-wieder.net/fail.png - doesn't look right here (osx 10.6, safari 5.1.7)